# Towny chat formatter

Tags: java, performance, parsing

How can this be improved,to make it easier to maintain? There is so much boilerplate being thrown around, so is it possible to use annotations? I've seen one example from Stack Overflow, but it ended up using reflection in order to call the method.

I was already planning on somehow annotating these "variables" in order to automatically produce the documentation, to prevent the documentation going out of date.

[GitHub](https://github.com/ElgarL/TownyChat/blob/582796e43a0c3b0828c8a5655e8d693bfed94c00/src/com/palmergames/bukkit/TownyChat/TownyChatFormatter.java)

```
public class TownyChatFormatter {
private static StringReplaceManager<LocalTownyChatEvent> replacer = new StringReplaceManager<LocalTownyChatEvent>();

static {
    replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote("{worldname}"), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
            return String.format(ChatSettings.getWorldTag(), event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName());
        }
    });
    replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote("{town}"), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
            return event.getResident().hasTown() ? event.getResident().getTown().getName() : "";
        }
    });
```

Comment: `event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName()` Holy Demeter!:)

Comment: Coming back almost a year later I just figured to "thank" you for linking to an article or explaining what you even meant by demeter... I tried searching when you first mentioned it finding nothing due to not knowing the context.

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is the way to go. The library you depend so transparently on is not "object oriented". It uses beans. That means its creators expect it to be used reflectively for some reason.

Create a class to model the recurring concept:

```
class Replacement {
    String patern;
    String format;
    List<String> props;

    // getters, setters, etc...
}
```

Factor out the repetition to configuration:

```
# JSON-like config example
replacements: [{pattern:"{world}", format:"WORLD: %s", props:["event.player.world.name"]},
               {pattern:"{town}", format: ...so and so....}]
```

Load them from config and change the repeating code to a loop:

```
for (Replacement replacement: replacements) {
    replacer.registerFormatReplacement(
        Pattern.quote(replacement.getPatern()), 
        new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
            @Override
            public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
                Object[] params = getProps(event, replacement.getProps());
                return String.format(replacement.getFormat(), params);
            }
        });
}

static Object[] getProps(Object bean, List<String> properties) {
     // use BeanUtils or some such library to get each property
     // and fill an array
     // use empty string for nulls here
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, I don't know much about beans.

But its not just the Towny library that I will need to support, there are many libraries that I wish to support, as the plugin I'm working on is designed to run side by side with TownyChat, Towny and other plugins by other authors.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a String switch, and can't use Java 8 yet (lambda expressions should greatly simplify your existing code), you could use something like the following (which replaces the use of inner classes with a single switch):

```
static {
    register("{worldname}", "{town}");
}

private static void register(final String... patterns) {
    for (final String pattern : patterns) {
        replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote(pattern), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
            @Override
            public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
                switch (pattern) {
                    case "{worldname}": return String.format(ChatSettings.getWorldTag(), event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName());
                    case "{town}": return event.getResident().hasTown() ? event.getResident().getTown().getName() : "";
                    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You would have to profile this to see whether the use of a switch made performance worse or better though (could be better, as the single registered function might be inlined and the switch should be fast).  You could also use constants variables instead of strings, but that would increase code size.

Comment: are string switches java 6 or 7, I'm restricted to 6 unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Unfortunately, String switches are in Java 7.